# Async In Targeting .NET 4.0 Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, task

I am using the below syntax in my webform .net 4.0 project.  However, once it hits the `dropdown1.DataSource = tasks[0].Result.Tables[0];` I get a `NullReferenceException` error.

I know generally this error is thrown because a proper assignment was not made, however, in my syntax it looks to me like I made all applicable assignments needed.  What do I need to alter/change/modify in my syntax below in order to have the drop down populated appropriately?

```
namespace NETAsyncLowVersion
{
public partial class WebformLVAsync : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private class1 _class1 = new NC1();
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[]{ SqlQuery1() }, tasks =>
            {
                try 
                {
                    dropdown1.DataSource = tasks[0].Result.Tables[0];
                }
                catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
    }
    private void SqlQuery1()
    {
        dropdown1.DataSource = _class1.SqlQuery1(databaseconn);
    }

public class class1
{
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    private Databaselayer _Databaselayer = new Databaselayer();

    public DataSet SqlQuery1(string databaseConnection)
    {
        DS = new DataSet();
        _Databaselayer.SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        _Databaselayer.SqlQueryBuilder.Append("Select managername from salesdatabase");
        return _Databaselayer.FDS(databaseConnection, _Databaselayer.SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
    }           
}
public class Databaselayer
{
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> FDS(string connectionString, string sqlQuery)
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connectionString))
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            return dataSet;
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where did yo got tasks[0]? Make sure it exists and also check if it's not null

Comment: @Saleem - to my understanding isn't that the Task<DataSet> that I am returning from my DatabaseLayer class?  I know the sqlQuery returns results if I run it directly in SQL Server.

Comment: Your code is not complete: you cannot cast System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> to DataSet

Comment: @Jeroen - so the issue stems from my Databaselayer where I use System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> but try to return a dataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked about this in another question: [Use 1 DataReader For Multiple Database Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947919/use-1-datareader-for-multiple-database-calls/35948728#35948728). In your case, you're in a user control, then you need to call **Page.RegisterAsyncTask** method instead of simply **RegisterAsyncTask**

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard Has you added the extension method's class in your codebase?