# Use Parameter Query With RegisterAsyncTask

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, task

@Micha-kun pointed me to a great example of how to do a stored procedure with no params or just a straight sql query.  However, what if I need to to do 3 stored procedures 2 with no params and 1 with params?

```
private Task LoadDataAsync()
{
  var t1 = ExecuteQueryAsync(databaseConnection, "exec FirstGraders ");
  var t2 = ExecuteQueryAsync(databaseConnection, "exec SecondGraders ");
  var t3 = ExecuteQueryAsync(databaseConnection, "exec ThirdGraders ");
  return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { t1, t2, t3 }, _ => {
    gv1.DataSource = t1.Result;
    gv1.DataBind();
    gv2.DataSource = t2.Result;
    gv2.DataBind();
    gv3.DataSource = t3.Result;
    gv3.DataBind();
  });
}
```

So in the sample above, let's say that the stored proc `exec ThirdGraders` takes a string (varchar in sql server) parameter of `@teacher` - could I still use the working example I was given from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947919/use-1-datareader-for-multiple-database-calls/35948728#35948728) to add parameters to only 1 stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
private Task<DataSet> ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(string connectionString, string sqlQuery, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        try
        {
            connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionString].ToString();
            dbconn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            cm = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbconn);
            dbconn.Open();
            cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
            if (params != null) {
                foreach(var pair in parameters)
                {
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                }
            }

            datasetttt = new DataSet();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
            da.Fill(datasetttt, "Data");
            return datasetttt;
        }
        catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
        finally
        {
            dbconn.Close();
            cm.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

I haven't tried this code. If fails, fix the nuisances. Then in your code you could use something like this:

```
var t1 = ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(cnx, "SELECT * FROM SomeTable"); // Without params
var t2 = ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(
            cnx, 
            "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Property1 = @Value",
            new Dictionary<string, object> 
                {
                    {"@Value", 12}
                }); // With params
```